# Google Analytics non-interaction trackEvent not firing

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to use Google Analytics' recently added feature that allows you to designate an event as a non-interaction event using the "opt_noninteraction" flag. However, when I set the flag to both true or false, the event fails to fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you're probably not setting the value parameter.  Make sure you have the value parameter in there (the 4th parameter) just before true as follows.

Value Parameter Undefined
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Examplecategory', 'ExampleAction', 'ExampleLabel',, true]);"

Value Parameter Defined
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Examplecategory', 'ExampleAction', 'ExampleLabel', 1 , true]);"

Jim Snyder
Empirical Path

Comment: Yeah, this was a major brain fart on my part. Thanks for the help!